# Is use of static variables good practice for storing variables when transitioning between viewControllers?

Tags: swift, static, sprite-kit, global-variables

I'm creating a game using `spriteKit`. In `landscape` mode, the gameBoard is shown, and when switching to `portrait` an info screen is shown. Now, going back to the `landscape` mode, the gameBoard is reinitialized, resetting all the changes made before switching device orientation.

I have solved this by storing the `data` in a `class` with `static` `variables`. It works, but it seems to be that there might be some issues with this approach. Since the `static` `variables` are accessible in pretty much the whole app, and they always contain a value, they seem to me to be close to `global` `variables`. I know they are not the same, but keeping permanent `variables` in the background sounds like being heavy on memory, thus draining performance.

Am I right in this or is it fine? If it's a bad approach, what should I do to save the state when switching between `viewControllers`?

From what I have read, it's a bit unambiguous whether `static` variables are "OK" or not, so I would love a definit answer on this one (if there is one).

Comment: At the start of the post you are talking about switching orientations, but towards the end you started talking about switching between VCs. So does this mean you switch between VCs by rotating your device?

Comment: just make sure you cover(Thread Safety, Code Implicity)

Comment: @Sweeper Oh, sorry, let me clarify. When I switch orientation of the device, I also switch viewController, so the instance data from the previous viewController is gone.

Comment: @Sanad Barjawi Ok, thanks, will look it up. You don't happen to have a good resource to share?

Comment: https://dev.to/mervinsv/why-global-variables-are-bad-4pj

Comment: Your problem comes down to you creating a new scene on rotate....... avoid recreating the scene.

Comment: @KnightOfDragon But I want to create a new scene on rotation. Is there a way to do this without having the view destroyed?

Comment: why? That makes no sense.  I would be upset that everytime I get a phone call, my game resets because I switched to portrait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Advantages**

1. Can do meta object operations ( like validating something before creating objects , keep count of number of objects )
2. Can do operations which have nothing to do with objects but still you want them to be tied to Class.

**Disadvantages**

Commonly used to static variables sometime leads to problems due to access by different objects.

1. Are not tied to objects so doesn't reflect pure Object Oriented
   approach.
2. Needs to be synchronized so as to avoid update conflicts by mutiple
   objects and threads. it does mention why sometimes the usage of
   static functions and variable might be bad

**Check the following article for more info,**

https://r.je/static-methods-bad-practice
Hope it helps

Comment: Well, that article was very clear on the topic lol. But my question remains on what to use instead to save the viewController state.

Comment: make use of delegates or closure to pass the state between the two controllers, or you could make use of UserDefaults.